# Truncate ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm displaying some content using the following bit of code:

```
<% foreach ( var m in ViewData.Model) { %>

<div class="content">
<%= m.article %>
</div>
```

Which shows a news article from my database. What I want to do is truncate the story to be smaller, how do would I do this? Also the article column contains HTML tags such as `<p>` so therefore splitting up the article purely on character numbers would cause issues.

Any ideas on where to start? I'm new to MVC.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not a simple problem, but you can start by using the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

> This is an agile HTML parser that
>   builds a read/write DOM and supports
>   plain XPATH or XSLT (you actually
>   don't HAVE to understand XPATH nor
>   XSLT to use it, don't worry...). It is
>   a .NET code library that allows you to
>   parse "out of the web" HTML files. The
>   parser is very tolerant with "real
>   world" malformed HTML. The object
>   model is very similar to what proposes
>   System.Xml, but for HTML documents (or
>   streams).

Once you have your DOM in memory you can then extract or truncate elements in a way that will not break the DOM structure, e.g., you can remove entire `<p></p>` nodes, or just truncate some fo the text within that node.

Comment: Hi, I don't want to download any additional stuff. I want to use purely the default framework.

Comment: The default framework does not contain anything to handle the messiness that is HTML. If you know that your content is valid XHTML (or you can convert it to be), then just use the XML classes in C# to do something similar.

Comment: Yes it is valid XHTML. Would you be able to explain how to do that. As like I said I'm new to C# and MVC and so not really sure what you mean.

Comment: Or copy paste the code from the library you don't want to download.

Comment: @Paco: HtmlAgilityPack is provided as source.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have control over how articles are submitted? Perhaps you can ask for a short intro/summary. I believe WordPress does it.

Or have the user insert a marker which signifies the end of intro/summary. something like:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<!-- END INTRO -->
<p>Ut malesuada porttitor consectetur. </p>
```

You can display it without any consequences and still "split" the article programmatically.